# Why flyway.locations property has no effect, if specified in config file and loaded from userdirectory by flyway itself?

Tags: flyway

I'm using Flyway Community Edition 5.1.4 and am trying to run migrations from two different directories with maven. I created an example project, which can be downloaded from [this github repository](https://github.com/ineart/flyway-example).

I created 2 flyway migration scripts: 1st in `src/main/resources/dir1` and 2nd in `src/main/resources/dir2`. `flyway.conf` is placed in project root directory.

**Case 1:**
Run command: `mvn flyway:info`
Output: No migrations found ([Screenshot case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Lvq.png))

This is ok, because migration scripts are not in standard driectory `src/main/resources/db/migration`

**Case 2:**
Run command: `mvn flyway:info -Dflyway.configFiles=/flyway.conf`
Output: both migration scripts are found ([Screenshot case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4iY9.png))

In case 2 the flyway config file is specified explicitly in maven command to load migration scripts from both directories `classpath:/dir1` and `classpath:/dir2`. However flyway can load `flyway.conf` by itself. The config file should be present in `<userhome>` directory. So if i put the same `flyway.conf` file in my userhome directory, the file is loaded (i can see this if i run maven command with -X switch), but flyway do not find the migration scripts.

**Case 3:**
Run command: `mvn flyway:info -X`
Output: No migrations found ([Screehshot case 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JahkQ.png)), although the same config file is loaded. Visible in maven output: `[DEBUG] Loading config file: C:\Users\username\flyway.conf`

This happens only with `flyway.locations` property. Other properties like `flyway.url=`, `flyway.user` etc. work fine, even in case 3.

So the question is, why `flyway.locations` property has no effect, if `flyway.conf` file is loaded from `userdirectory` by flyway itself?

Comment: Could you try to be more specific about what you are trying to archieve? Could you add sample of what you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited the original post and added more detailed description. I hope now the problem is more clear.